# ajax.beginform - OnFailure dont return partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform

> Hello
>
> > I am using ajax.beginform and i want to return partial view with the
> >     errors inside. whan I change the status code to something bad to fire
> >     the OnFailure  method it is not returning the partial view. the view that called:

```
<fieldset>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveSocioDetails", "Student", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "firstsuccess",OnFailure = "sociodetailsfail", UpdateTargetId="partialsocio" ,LoadingElementId = "div_loading" }, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="partialsocio">
    @Html.Action("PartialSocioDetails", "Student", new { SpId = ViewBag.SpId })
</div>
        <div id="div_loading" style="display:none;">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Pic/Spinner.gif")" alt="" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">שלח</button>
}
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

> my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SaveSocioDetails(SpSocio socio) // ajax for 1 step in socio
        {
            socio.StudentId = sStudentId; // bind student id to socio model
            bool sociook = SocioDetValid(socio);
            // add validation
            if (ModelState.IsValid && sociook)
            {
                SaveSocioModel(socio);
                Response.StatusCode = 200;
            }
            else
               Response.StatusCode = 300; // return error to client the model is not valid
            return PartialView("~/Views/Student/Socio/SocioDetails.cshtml", socio); // return the partial view of the forn with validation messages
        }
```

> js:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function ()
    {
    });

    function firstsuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#partialsocio').html(data);
        console.log('this is ajaxSuccess');
    }

    function sociodetailsfail(bdata) {
         console.log('this is ajaxfail');
        console.log(data);
        $('#partialsocio').html(data);
    }
</script>
```

> please help me out with this

Comment: Do you have a reference for `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your page?

Comment: Yes I have add this reference

Comment: What is the order of your references? Can you show us how did you reference them?

Comment: I have got the problem, the text was inside the code that has returned

Answer (score -1):

If your request fails then you will get the callback from server including problem definition inside `sociodetailsfail` witin java-script, where you can put logic to display error messages that you receive from server **`bdata`** object to user

Comment: But the bdata is not return the partial view that I want to reload in the view. He has the error code without partial view inside